# How i can set an index with parameters under nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

under Apache I can set the index very easy. Like:

*DirectoryIndex index.php?parameter=xyz*

**How can I set this in nginx?**

I had tried: index index.php?parameter=xyz but I get an 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but its practically an API:

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

```
    # wordpress (without WP Super Cache) - example 1
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    # wordpress (without WP Super Cache) - example 2 
    # It doesn't REALLY need the "q" parameter, but without an explicit $args php 
    # gets an empty QUERY_STRING, breaking generated responses that don't use a 
    # permalink, such as search results.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    # joomla
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

     location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
    # if not already defined in the fastcgi_params file
     # any other specific fastcgi_params
    }
```

Obviously those examples are for the try_files, but parameters would be the same passed in.  This is just an example where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

In nginx, options for index are files. But I think you can try:

```
index index.html /index.php?q=1
```

If it does not work, why don't just use `index index2.php` then in your index2.php you redirect to index.php?q=1?